# How to get Router params when using pipe in combination with skipWhile?

Tags: angular, router, angular-activatedroute

I have a dynamic BreadCrumb navigation where I need to get the params from URL. To achieve this, I'am executing the following code:

```
const userId = this.activatedRoute.params
               .pipe(skipWhile((params: Params) => Number.isNaN(+params['userId'])));

const getAppUserId = userId.pipe(
            switchMap((params: Params) => {
                return +params['userId']
                    ? this.myAppService.getApplicationUser(+params['userId'])
                    : of('')
            }))
```

But it's always empty and I never get the params passed to the Observable. When I use **`queryParams`**, it works fine, but I don't want to go for **`queryParams`** concept.
Any idea where I'am going wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [Stacklitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or any other [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce your error.

Comment: @zerocewl: I'am trying to provide a Stackblitz Demo. Need a bit time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. Was kind of simple...the fix was to catch the param from **`route.snapshot`**.

```
this.router.events
        .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
        .pipe(map(() => {return this.activatedRoute;}))
        .pipe(
            map((route) => {
                while (route.firstChild) {route = route.firstChild;}
                return route;
            })
        ).subscribe(route => {
             console.log(`param: ${route.snapshot.params['id']}`);
             ...
             ...
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I once made an automated breadcrumb builder that only relies on a static data in your routes. I managed to find it back, so here you go, in case it helps :

```js
export class RouteBreadcrumbsComponent {

  breadcrumbs = [];

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    let buffer = [];

    /* 
       Listen for router events in reverse order (to get all events).
       From the snapshots, return its path and its breadcrumb.
    */
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof ActivationEnd),
      map((event: ActivationEnd) => [
        event.snapshot.data && event.snapshot.data.crumb || undefined,
        this.determineCorrectPath(event.snapshot),
      ]),
      filter(([crumb, url]) => !!crumb),
    ).subscribe(([crumb, url]) => buffer.push({ crumb, url }));

    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(event => {
      this.breadcrumbs = buffer.reverse();
      buffer = [];
    });
  }

  determineCorrectPath(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    const path = snapshot.routeConfig.path;
    const params = snapshot.params;

    // Path = route with a param, so get the param
    if (path.startsWith(':'))
      return params[path.replace(':', '')];
    // Path = '' = route group or root route of a lazy loaded module, so take the parent path
    else if (!path)
      return snapshot.parent.routeConfig.path;
    // Path can be used as is
    else
      return path;
  }

  buildRoutingArray(crumbIndex: number) {
    return this.breadcrumbs
      .slice(0, crumbIndex + 1)
      .map(crumb => crumb.url)
      .join('/');
  }
}
```

All you have to do is provide a `data: { crumb: 'Your component crumb' }` to each of your routes and it should work.

Comment: Not working as expected. Dosen't show nothing. Didn't you miss any thing? Should `buildRoutingArray(crumbIndex: number)` not be invoked? As it looks now, it's not invoked at all.

Comment: @k.vincent [it works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eu8uuh?file=src%2Fapp%2Froute-breadcrumbs%2Froute-breadcrumbs.component.html). But I'm not giving it so that you can use it, I'm giving it to help you understand how it works. So no, I didn't miss anything, it works as epxected, and `buildRoutingArray` is a HTML function that displays the crumbs.

Comment: Ok. I get it. Great. I'll follow the approach.

Comment: I see. Good one. But my issue is to get param `id` from/via observable and after that use it for: `getAppUserId` with switchMap to make a HTTP call with the param `id` which I got from `snapshot.params`. This where I'am stuck.

Comment: @k.vincent making another answer for that, wait a minute

Answer (score 0):

First issue :

```
Number.isNaN(+params['userId'])
```

Returns a string, not a number.

Second issue :

```
const getAppUserId = userId.pipe(
  switchMap((params: Params) => {
```

You're not getting the params from the observable, but the user ID (well, a boolean actually).

If your wish is to "get param id from/via observable and after that use it for: getAppUserId with switchMap to make a HTTP call with the param id which I got from snapshot.params"

Then the correct code would be

```
this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
  map(params => params.id),
  switchMap(userId => this.myAppService.getApplicationUser(userId)
);
```

You should not test the validity of the ID : URL are strings, you can't trust a user. Simply make the request, and if the ID doesn't match anything, then your API won't return anything. Let the API make all the controls on the ID, not your client.

Comment: Still no `params.id`. I changed `userId` to be: `this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(skipWhile((params: Params) => params['id']))` 
I think the issue is still in this part where I'am using `skipWhile`. Do you mind if can continue in chatRoom instead of here?

Comment: @k.vincent you can, but I'm going to answer even less (I have stack notifications on my phone but not for the chat room). Best would be to make a [mcve] of your issue so that I can see it first hand and correct it.

Comment: Here is a demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m36dmr, but it's not working, as I tried to get all the necessary files but the concept is a kind of large and complicated that I can provide all files. But the demo would give you enough idea what I'am really trying to rech.